# Создать двумерный массив из вещественных чисел с рандомными числами C#

Tags: c#, массивы

Не получается создать двумерный массив с вещественными числами, с `int` вроде все ок без проблем, а вот рандомный вещественный двумерный никак не додумаю

```
double[,] a = new double[5, 10];
 
Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        a[i, j] = random.Next(100);
        Console.Write("{0,4}", a[i, j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Код работает, но вещественные числа не выходят типа `15,34`

Comment: просто `int` поменяйте на `double`, а `rnd.Next` на `rnd.NextDouble()`

Comment: не помогло, ошибки выходят

Comment: у вас вопрос по работе кода, но код вы не показываете. Отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте код, в котором ошибки. Опишите какие ошибки в каких строках возникают.

Comment: У меня этот код работает. Что здесь не так?

Comment: он то работает, но вещественные числа не выходят типа 15,34

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самом деле числа вещественные, просто их надо отформатировать, типа `"{0,6:F2}"`, тогда вы увидите нули после запятой. Если вам нужны не нули, то это надо либо генерить целые до 10000, преобразовать в `double` и делить на 100, либо использовать `NextDouble()`.

```cs
double[,] a = new double[5, 10];

Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
    {
        a[i, j] = random.NextDouble() * 100; // NextDouble() дает случайное вещественное число в диапазоне от 0 до 1
        Console.Write("{0,6:F2}", a[i, j]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

```
  6,72 60,22 24,42 84,20 12,61 30,64 93,47  3,50 22,79  4,34
 95,71 90,95 44,50 21,76  1,87 80,73 32,53 40,60  0,96 67,08
 41,52 24,01 95,61 63,47 75,61 62,24 24,47 94,76 23,46 20,95
 19,74 26,59 48,49 41,25 36,37 14,57 47,68 54,40 53,48 55,64
 60,67 24,19 98,83 87,44  9,94 86,21 10,73  9,66 74,33  8,64
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    // Метод заполнения массива случайными вещественными числами от -10 до 10
double[,] FillMatrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    double [,] array = new double[rows, cols];
    Random rand = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            array[i, j] = Math.Round(rand.Next(-100, 101)*0.1, 1);
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```